# Merging an Angular SPA with Telerik RadControls

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, rad-controls

Our company is beginning to migrate a LARGE legacy codebase from the Microsoft MVC mindset (where everything happens on the server) to more of a Web 2.0 approach, where the communications are mostly data instead of a bunch of post-backs.

I prototyped the first tool to integrate into the legacy system, and have it working just fine, but now that I am integrating the code with the legacy system, I am finding there are a LOT of unexpected behaviors.

I am using Angular to manage the SPA aspects (including browser-side routing).

Two particular issues I am having:

- When I click a button that was created in a custom directive, a post-back is triggered.  The script behind this button sets an internal data value and does not have any reason to trigger a post-back.
- Something is interfering with my data bound controls so that they do not render correctly.

I expect these issues are related, and I have tried searching for the last 2 or 3 days, but I cannot find ANYTHING to help me figure this out.

Our legacy system is (of course) ASP, with Master Pages and Telerik controls.

Please help - even just tips or clues about what might be going on will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there was an underlying form with an event (I can't remember whether it was an onChange or an onSubmit event) that was being triggered.

To fix the issue, I just had to clear the event.  I couldn't really find where the event was being embedded into the code (somewhere deep in Telerik base controls, I suspect), but I was able to add "post-load" code that removed the event handler.

Comment: I recently had to add another SPA to my Telerik site, and I found a great solution: Use an IFrame with a transparent background.